# Append an HTML tag, including an `onclick` attribute, to a page dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap/Cordova application. I'm trying to dynamically append HTML to a container. The appended HTML has an anchor tag that includes an inline `onclick` event for the links to open on a click on iOS and Android, however I keep getting the error in the console

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localData.length; i++) {
    $('.best-deals-page #deals-container').append('<a href="#" onclick="window.open('  + localData[i].deepLink + ' +  '_system'  ); "> ' + '</a>');
}
```

Comment: Grammar; sentences structured for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape single quotes in your window.open():

```
for( var i=0;  i < localData.length;  i++) {
    $('.best-deals-page #deals-container').append('<a href="#"   onclick="window.open(\'  + localData[i].deepLink + \' +  \'_system\'  ); "> </a>');
}
```

Comment: You are welcome!  Maybe you can accept the answer then.